# Solving Time Dependent Schrödinger's Equation in Rotating Frame

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

My Hamiltonian is: $\frac{1}{\hbar}\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\Delta \hat{\sigma _z} + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon _d \hat{\sigma _x}$ where $\Delta$ is a constant made of frequencies.

I need to solve my TDSE assuming the system is prepared in the initial state $| \psi (t=0)\rangle =|0\rangle$.

This is what I have tried. I basically made a matrix representation of the hamiltonian:

$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\Delta & \epsilon_d \\ \epsilon_d & -\Delta\end{bmatrix}$$
With eigenvalues: $\lambda _{\pm} = \pm \sqrt{\Delta ^2 + \epsilon_d ^2}$

I can say that the general solution is with the form: $|\psi \rangle = \Sigma_{\lambda} a_{\lambda} e^{-i\lambda t}|\lambda \rangle$

This is where I am stuck, I can't find the coefficients even the initial conditions I just don't see how to advance. I'm not even sure if my approach is right!

Any ideas?

Comment: The expansion coefficients are computed by taking the inner product of the initial state with the basis states (provided all the state are normalized), so you need to compute $\langle + | 0 \rangle$ and $\langle - | 0 \rangle$, where $| \pm \rangle$ are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.